# numpy, same calculation different result

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate  [this fomula](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=((P%5E%7BT%7DP)%5E%7B-1%7DP%5E%7BT%7DP)%5E%7B-1%7D(P%5E%7BT%7DP)%5E%7B-1%7DP%5E%7BT%7DPA).
I think the result is A.
So I write a python code using numpy.
But depending on the computation sequence, result is not A.
What brought this on?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import *
import decimal

#generate matrix A
A = randn(180,240)
A = np.array(A, dtype = decimal.Decimal )

#generate matrix P
h,w=A.shape
P = randn(0.9*h,h)
P = np.array(P, dtype = decimal.Decimal )

#it's OK. IA = A
PP = dot(P.T,P)
PPinv = np.linalg.inv(PP)
PPinvPP = dot(PPinv,PP)
PPinvPPinv = np.linalg.inv(PPinvPP)
I = dot(PPinvPPinv,PPinvPP)
IA = dot(I, A)

#I think IA2 must be A. but not A. Why?
PA = dot(P,A)
PPA = dot(P.T,PA)
PPinvPPA = dot(PPinv,PPA)
IA2 = dot(PPinvPPinv, PPinvPPA)

#print result
print "A;%0.2f" % A[0,0]
print "IA:%0.2f" % IA[0,0]
print "IA2:%0.2f" % IA2[0,0]
```

Comment: I can only guess, but I'd say - welcome to the wonderful world of discrete numerics, where `(a*b)*c != a*(b*c)` is a reality. You probably need to define equality with an epsilon for comparison.

Comment: None of your arrays are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is when you use non-square matrix P, where height is less than width, determinant of the PP always has a zero value, but because of a calc error it's != 0. So after this it's impossible to calculate the real PPinv and any forward steps are meaningless.

```
P = randn(2,3)
P = np.array(P, dtype = decimal.Decimal )

PP = dot(P.T,P)
np.linalg.det(PP) #-5.2536080570332981e-34
```

So why is IA == A?

I think it's a situation when error*error gives you a normal result.

How to solve it?

1. Do not use Python for theoretical questions :)
2. Change P = randn(0.9*h,h) to P = randn(1.1*h,h)

Comment: I've got a question for you (but still I can't comment under your answer): is it true that det(AAT) (where A.shape == (n,n-1), so AAT.shape == (n,n)) is always == 0, or only most of the time?

Comment: The main idea is that we can't get more information (e.g. (n,n-1) -> (n,n)) without using it's linear combination.

Comment: Well, we know that `Rank(AB) <= min(Rank(A), Rank(B))`, If we apply that we get directly, that `AA'` has a maximum rank of `n-1`, therefore is singular and therefore `det(AA') == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is quite interesting:

In general your formula is only correct if `PP` is non-singular.

So why then `AI == A`?

```
PP = dot(P.T,P)
PPinv = np.linalg.inv(PP)
PPinvPP = dot(PPinv,PP)
PPinvPPinv = np.linalg.inv(PPinvPP)
I = dot(PPinvPPinv,PPinvPP)
IA = dot(I, A)
```

There are a couple of things to note here:

- `PP = dot(P.T,P)` is singular
- => `PPinv` is not a true inverse
- but `PPinvPP` is invertible, so `I` is indeed the identity matrix

**Note:** You only get `AI == A` because of your special order of evaluation of the terms.

In the second calculation of `IA2` term you don't have this special evaluation order that gives you `A` as result.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you could use [Sympy](http://sympy.org) for these kind of problems:

```
from IPython.display import display
import sympy as sy


sy.init_printing()  # For LaTeX-like pretty printing in IPython

n = 5
A = sy.MatrixSymbol('A', 162, 240)  # dimension 162x240
P = sy.MatrixSymbol('P', 162, 180)  # dimensions 162x180

PTP = P*P.T
ex1 = (PTP.inverse() * PTP).inverse() * PTP.inverse() * PTP * A
display(ex1)  # displays: A
```